R, how to get current time miliseconds, without extra information ? (Sys.time(), format("%X"))
I have tried to get just the current miliseconds from the current second in R with the following code:

options("digits.secs" = 6) # since 6 is the maximum digits for seconds apparently

Sys.time()


So, it returns the full date with the miliseconds.
2024-10-09 14:35:51.687084 CEST
But if i just want to have the miliseconds what should i do with format() ?
I have tried,
options(digits.secs = 6)

format(Sys.time(), "%X")

But it only returns the following:
14:35:51
I just want it to return 687084
I know i can do the following but it does not look optimal:
options("digits.secs" = 6)
unlist(strsplit(x = as.character(Sys.time()), split = "\\."))[2]

Do you have any idea how to do it?
Thanks.

Are you referring to milliseconds or nanoseconds?

No format will give the seconds' decimal part, you have to extract from the value representing a date/time. In R, objects of class "POSIXct" are represented as numbers.
Two ways.

Use base function substring to extract the decimal digits as characters;
Use modular arithmetic.

secs_decimal1 <- function(x) {
  if(missing(x)) x <- Sys.time()
  substring(x, 21L)
}
secs_decimal2 <- function(x) {
  if(missing(x)) x <- Sys.time()
  unclass(x) %% 1L
}

# save the current setting
op <- options("digits.secs" = 6)

x <- Sys.time()
secs_decimal1(x)
#> [1] "344074"
secs_decimal2(x)
#> [1] 0.344074
options(op)

Created on 2024-10-09 with reprex v2.1.0

Ah really nice, did not know about substring
Thanks.

So it should work until the year 10000 :)

@JulienLarget-Piet I have added a numeric version, returning the decimal part of the time.

Yes, just saw it, really cool. Just what i needed.

You can convert as.POSIXlt. From this list format you can extract fractional seconds, use modulo %% 1 and...
...multiply by one thousand to get milliseconds,
> x <- Sys.time()
> strftime(x, '%F %H:%M:%OS3')  ## display
[1] "2024-10-09 16:39:24.150" 
> (as.POSIXlt(x)$sec %% 1)*1e3  ## extract
[1] 150.933

or multiply by one million to get microseconds,
> strftime(x, '%F %H:%M:%OS6')  ## display
[1] "2024-10-09 16:39:24.150933"
> (as.POSIXlt(x)$sec %% 1)*1e6  ## extract
[1] 150933

or multiply by one billion to get nanoseconds.
> strftime(x, '%F %H:%M:%OS9')  ## not possible to display
[1] "2024-10-09 16:39:24.150933"
> (as.POSIXlt(x)$sec %% 1)*1e9  ## nut extract
[1] 150933027


Interesting, will try that later. Thanks!
